# Send Email from Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We want to send tutors an email about their student information every time they fill out a form. When a tutor fills out the form for a student, the tutors email populates in column E for that student. Then, column F is changed to "No." We want to send emails only to tutors who have "No" in column F.

Is there a way to ensure that after the email is sent only to those with "No", then those cells are changed to "Yes"?

```
function newmatchEmail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var data=sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();

data.forEach(function(row,col){
if (col == '') return;
if (row[0] == '') return; //If ColA is empty skip
if (row[4] == '') return; //If ColE is empty skip
if (row[5] == "No") // we want ONLY tutors that have "No" in column F to receive an email; unsure if correct

  var info = row[0];
  var studentname = row[2];
  var studentemail = row[3];

  var tutoremail = row[4];
  var subject = "Student Opening Request";
  var messagetemplate = sheet1.getRange(2,8).getValue();

  message=messagetemplate.replace("<studentname>",studentname).replace("<info>",info).replace("<studentemail>",studentemail);

  MailApp.sendEmail(tutoremail, subject, message);
  data.getRange(2,6,getLastRow).setValue("Yes"); // after email, change column F to "Yes" for those emailed; unsure if correct
})
}
```

Our code has some weak points commented by //. We aren't too good with coding so any advice is greatly appreciated--especially if verbatim :)

[Tutor-Student List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ut4c.png)
[Email Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZROU.png)

Comment: When I saw your script, I think that your script sends the emails using the email addresses retrieved from the column "E" of "Active Student List" sheet. So, I cannot understand your situation of `The issue is that it doesn't seem to send emails to every tutor in column E of the "Active Student List" Sheet, only the first email in the column.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? By the way, I thought that `<studentemail` of `replace("<studentemail",studentemail)` might be `<studentemail>`. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Sorry! We updated our question to reflect some changes. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use a **forEach** loop to solve your problem. Regarding the template I would have just included it into the code. Basically a forEachloop allows you to read every row going downwards and extract a unique data for each run. Can read more bout the forEach() loop using this link: https://spreadsheet.dev/foreach-loop-in-apps-script

I have provided my way of writing the code for your situation below. The message I kinda butchered it cause I was too lazy to type a long message :P. Let me know if you face any issues replicating the code.

```
function newmatchEmail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Active Student List');
var data=sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();

data.forEach(function(row,col){
if (col == '') return;
if (row[0] == '') return; //If ColA is empty skip
if (row [6] == false) return; //Skip if the checkbox is not checked in Col G
if (row [5] == 'YES') return; //Skip if the email has been sent in ColF

var info = row[0];
var name = row[2];
var studentemail = row[3];

var tutoremail = row[4];
var subject = "Student Opening Request";
var message = "Thank You So Much\n\nHere is the basic info: " + `${info}` 
 + "\nStudent Name: " + `${name}`
 + "\nStudent Email: " + `${studentemail}`
 + "\n\nPlease do not hesitate to ask questions";

MailApp.sendEmail(tutoremail, subject, message);

data.getRange(col + 1, 6).setValue('YES'); //Imprint YES in ColF once the email has been sent

data.getRange('G2:G').setValue(false); //Reset the checkboxes in ColG to null after emails/process is completed
});

}
```

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you! So now *almost* everything works. The emails send when I run the match function, and we now need to discover how we can only send emails to tutors just with a "No" in column F and then change that to "Yes" upon submission. More details are in the updated post.

Comment: Hey ok what I would add on to do is have another column before/after ColF acting as a checkbox maybe title "Select to Send". So for checking if the emails you have sent, instead of YES and NO, I would recommend just using YES. So it will only send those that you have checked and once sent imprint the word YES in the next col so it wont send anymore. 

I will re-edit my code. 

Summary:
1. Add another column after Col F, title "To Send"

Comment: So the code relies on Col G as the checkbox col to determine who it should send to

Comment: Perfect! Yes, that's what we actually thought to do as well. However, we have encountered a few issues with that currently. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71453878/update-sheet-based-on-email-send.

Comment: Hey saw it. I believe a simple  .setValue() should be sufficient.