# Update Sheet Based on Email Send

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We want to send tutors an email with student info every time they fill out a form. When a tutor fills out the form for a student, the tutors email populates in column E for that student. Then, column F is changed to "No." We want to send emails only to tutors who have "No" in column F.

Currently, our function serves this purpose. However, we *also* want that after an email is sent, it changes the "No" in colF to "Yes" to prevent future emails. We tried to use a forloop but we aren't too savvy with coding, and it does not change "No" to "Yes" at all. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
function newmatchEmail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Active Student List');
var data=sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();

data.forEach(function(row,col){
if (col == '') return;
if (row[0] == '') return; //If ColA is empty skip
if (row[4] == '') return; //If ColE is empty skip
if (row[5] == "Yes") return; //If ColF is "Yes" skip
if (row[5] ==  "") return; //If ColF is empty skip
if (row[5] == "No") // we want ONLY tutors that have "No" in column F to receive an email

  var studentinfo = row[0];
  var studentname = row[2];
  var studentemail = row[3];

  var tutoremail = row[4];
  var subject = "Student Opening Request";
  var messagetemplate = sheet1.getRange(2,8).getValue();

  message=messagetemplate.replace("<studentinfo>",studentinfo).replace("<studentname>",studentname).replace("<studentemail>",studentemail);

  MailApp.sendEmail(tutoremail, subject, message);
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh=ws.getSheetByName('Active Student List');
  var values = sh.getRange("F2:F").getValues();
  for(var i in values){
       if (newvalues[i][0] == "No"){
         values.setValue([i][0]=="Yes");}} // something's not quite right here
})
}
```

[Image of Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSDvG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function newmatchEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Active Student List');
  // var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var data = sheet1.getRange("A2:F" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var rangeList = data.map(function (row, i) {
    if (row[0] == '' || row[4] == '' || row[5] == "" || row[5] == "Yes") return "";
    var studentinfo = row[0];
    var studentname = row[2];
    var studentemail = row[3];
    var tutoremail = row[4];
    var subject = "Student Opening Request";
    var messagetemplate = sheet1.getRange(2, 8).getValue();
    message = messagetemplate.replace("<studentinfo>", studentinfo).replace("<studentname>", studentname).replace("<studentemail>", studentemail);
    MailApp.sendEmail(tutoremail, subject, message);
    return "F" + (i + 2);
  }).filter(String);
  if (rangeList.length == 0) return;
  sheet1.getRangeList(rangeList).setValue("Yes");
}
```

- In this modification, when the email is sent, `Yes` is put to the column "F" of the same row.

  - When `setValue` is used in the loop, the process cost becomes high. So I used the value using RangeList.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setValue(value) of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setvaluevalue)

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your help. However, when we run your code as is we get the error message: "Exception: Invalid email: Tutor Email
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:14
newmatchEmail @ Code.gs:5". Unsure of what this means. For reference, row 14 is the MailApp.sendEmail function and row 5 is the var rangeList.

Comment: @Progress Point Tutoring Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your new issue of `However, when we run your code as is we get the error message: "Invalid email: Tutor Email (anonymous)`, in this case, my proposed modified script is not related to your this issue. Because the reason for your new issue is due to your Spreadsheet and the email address of `var tutoremail = row[4];`. So, can you confirm the column of email address? If you cannot understand my reply, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to check it.

Comment: @Progress Point Tutoring I confirmed that when your email address of `var tutoremail = row[4];` is the valid email address, no error occurs. So, please confirm it again?

Comment: @Progress Point Tutoring Thank you for replying. From your provided Spreadsheet, I thought that your current issue is due to `var data=sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();`. When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, the 1st row is header row. In the case of `var data=sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();`, the 1st row is retrieved. So in this case, I modified it to `var data = sheet1.getRange("A2:F" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();`. Please test it again.

Comment: Thank you so much! The only issue is that it has to be return "F" + (i+2) for it to work, but now it does. Thank you again, you have no idea how much this will help our program. ~ Blessings

Comment: @Progress Point Tutoring Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand from your additional information. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

Hey since you have already skipped the rows that are "Yes" and "", you can just use .setValue().

```
MailApp.sendEmail(tutoremail, subject, message);
data.getRange(col + 1, 6).setValue("Yes");
```