# Mail Merge with Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, mailmerge

i built a google sheet for my team result.
I need to send out "KPI report" in PDF for each staff.
The name is stored on (B2), and I have set a Vlookup to linkup the staff email (D2) for mail merge. Somehow it doesnt work. It bounds back with below error msg.

> Error
> Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient
> (anonymous) @ Trial.gs:37
> myFunction  @ Trial.gs:12

Can anyone advise solution?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Egyl8q6pgxiCx4Tu0Rv6nRUADQGTEMxoIEvkPBE0D8/edit?usp=sharing

```
function myFunction() {
// 1. Retrieve values from "Sheet2".
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Individual KPI Report");
 var values = sheet.getRange("A1:O29" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
 var template =  ss.getSheetByName("PDF");
 var ssId = ss.getId();
 var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
 var filenameOfPdf = template.getSheetName();
 
// 2. Create sheets for converting to PDF data.
 values.forEach(([v], i) => {
   // 1. Copy the sheet `PDF` as the template.
   var temp = template.copyTo(ss).setName("temp" + (i + 1));
   
   // 2. Set the name at the cell "B2".
   temp.getRange("B2").setValue(v);
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   var email = temp.getRange("D2").getValue();
   
   // 3. Export the template sheet as the PDF data.
   var subject = "Test Receipt ";
   var body = "\n Please see attached your current test receipt: ";
   var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ssId);
   var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
   + '&size=letter' // paper size legal / letter / A4
   + '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
   + '&fitw=true&source=labnol' // fit to page width, false for actual size
   + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
   + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
   + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
   + '&gid='; // the sheet's Id
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + temp.getSheetId(), {headers : {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token}}).getBlob().setName(filenameOfPdf + ".pdf");
   
   // 4. Send an email using the email corresponding to the name of "B2".
   if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
   GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {htmlBody : body,attachments : [response]});
   
   // 5. Delete the template sheet.
   ss.deleteSheet(temp);
 });
}
```

Comment: are you a virtual assistant?

Comment: No....I m not.....i m just a beginner of writing script to get easy of my job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its the sheet you were referencing to since the email is in Individual KPI Report

`var email = sheet.getRange("D2").getValues();`

Comment: Thank you so much. However, I dont get the part of "Btw I realize your UrlFetchApp function had some issues, I believe its because you are missing a createFile() function to create the PDF using the link."........would you please explain more to me....sorry for the problem.

Comment: Hey @Ker, sorry my bad I realise it was because I made a copy so the sheet id was slightly diff thus I got the error, please ignore my statement. Did the email function manage to work?

Comment: Currently, the mail merge works, but the attachment not. Email has been generated and sent out to the email. However, the it is a broken PDF attachment, and also it keep repeating to send email...(never stop)....

Comment: Can show what the broken PDF attachment looks like? Regarding the repeating email, I suspect its cause of the forEach loop, it is the correct function for this use case but might need to add a line of code/a field in sheets to indicate that it has been sent thus stopping the function.

Comment: You can download the attachment from below link. it is the attachment that sent from the email.                            https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dxUCTMzFQfgH53ZB17FAhUSqsWMIvbSk?usp=sharing

Comment: It could be that your gid is empty. https://prnt.sc/h0JL5VeiHM_8 // https://prnt.sc/gedBudN5haRv

Comment: I have worked on the script and did some modification. Finally it shows the attachment in the email, but the data is not correct. The name section disappear, and seems it doesnt send to every contact. it just keep sending to first contact continuously.

Comment: Hey @Ker, I checked  ```var email = temp.getRange("D2").getValue();``` it seems to be pulling from the correct cell but the cell is only showing one email. I suspect it is a google sheet formula issue, might want to check on that.

Comment: Regarding the email being sent continuously, it is because of the ```forEach``` function that puts the email creation in a loop. As mentioned, you could perhaps dedicate a cell to do a ```setValue("SENT")``` to indicate the email has been sent and have an ```if(cell == "SENT") return;``` to stop the function once the email was sent the first time

Comment: Alternatively you might want to set you ```.sendEmail()``` function outside the ```forEach()``` loop

Comment: the formula is correct. the email under Vlookup and will be depends on the name dropdown list (B2). Once it is selected a name, the email (D2) will be changed to new one.

Comment: Oh in that case, is the emails in D2 in the form of email1,email2,email3? Because if its not if wont send to the rest.

Comment: @Ker see if this helps regarding the ```.setValue()```: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71453878/update-sheet-based-on-email-send/71467192#71467192

Comment: yes, so i believe the problem is the selection on dropdown list doesnt work. once the dropdown list is working (loop each item), then it should have (email 1, email2, email3). Howerver, i dont know how to fix this..

Comment: hey i saw the the formula in D2 is a vlookup? Are you trying to get more than 1 email? Because vlookup can only get 1.

Comment: yes, D2 is a Vlookup. the logic is like this, copy the sheet to temp, then select name from B2, it shows email by D2 (Vlookup). and then send out. and loop again copy the sheet again, and select second name at B2, and work the same again.