# Specific form id submission - email trigger from spreadsheet data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-forms, eventtrigger

Looking for a way to trigger email script when specific form eg.form1 is submitted.

I have 2 forms form1 & form2, responses of both the forms are captured in 2 different sheets of same workbook.

I have a code in google app script to trigger email on submission of the google form shared below. While the code suggests the code be triggered on submission of specific form with formid, but the script is triggered even if form2 is also submitted.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
.forForm('xyz')
.onFormSubmit()
.create();

function myFunction(e) {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('14YicUUJeb3hopA7T7qydAN9ri__59_kmHfPpeURGlFg');
 var responseSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
 var rLastRow = responseSheet.getLastRow();
 var lastCol = responseSheet.getLastColumn();
 var values = responseSheet.getRange(rLastRow, 1, 1, lastCol).getValues()[0];

 var status = values[11];
 var ticketId = values[0];
 var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(values[1]), 'GMT+6', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a');
 var requestSubject = values[2];
 var requestType = values[2];
 var requestPriority = values[3];
 var requestDescription = values[4];
 var staffEmail = values[6];
 var facilityType = values[7];
 var facilityCode = values[8]
 
 if(status=='Open'){
var subject = '[Ticket ID: ' + ticketId + '] ' + requestSubject;

// Email Text. You can add HTML code here - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
var htmlBody = 'Dear IRT Team,';
htmlBody += '<p>This is to notify that there is a new service request from Unimove IRT Helpdesk portal.</p>';
htmlBody += '<p><strong>Request Type:</strong> ' + requestType;
htmlBody += '<br><strong>Request Date:</strong> ' + timestamp;
htmlBody += '<br><strong>Priority:</strong> ' + requestPriority;
htmlBody += '<br><strong>Description:</strong> ' + requestDescription;
htmlBody += '<br><strong>Facility Type:</strong> ' + facilityType;
htmlBody += '<br><strong>Facility Code:</strong> ' + facilityCode;
htmlBody += '<br><strong>Staff Email:</strong> ' + staffEmail + '</p>';
htmlBody += '<p>Above details extracted from <a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14YicUUJeb3hopA7T7qydAN9ri__59_kmHfPpeURGlFg/edit" target="_blank">Unimove IRT Helpdesk (Responses)</a>.</p>';
htmlBody += '<p>Thank you.</p>';
htmlBody += '<p>Regards,<br>Unimove IRT Helpdesk</p>';

GmailApp.sendEmail('vasuki.rao@snapdeal.com', subject, '', {htmlBody:htmlBody, name: 'Unimove IRT Helpdesk', replyTo: 'vasuki.rao@snapdeal.com'}); }
```

Comment: e.range.getSheet() will tell which sheet got edited and thus which form caused the submission trigger to fire.

Comment: Have you tried opening the form first using `FormApp.openByID()` instead of using the form ID directly on the `forForm()` method?

Comment: @DiegoSanchez Yes I have tried that also, var form = FormApp.openById('xyz'); and passing the variable, with no success

Comment: Just to confirm, basically what this needs to do is the trigger should only fire whenever form1 (and only form1) is submitted, is that correct?

Comment: Also, would you be able to update your script using the form object, instead of the form ID and clear every past triggers on the Trigger Section of the Apps Script UI. I'd recommend doing this using the incognito browser as well, and also provide a screenshot of the error / misbehavior of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried getting the sheet name that has been updated by the event? that way you could use that info to filter the responses.

```
function myFunction(e) {
 var updatedRow = e.range;
 var sheet = updatedRow.getSheet();
 var sheetName = sheet.getName();

 if (sheetName == targetSheetResponse){
  //Here you handle the filtered responses.
 }
}
```

If the piece of code above is not working for you, the reason might be that you are creating a new trigger at:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
.forForm('xyz')
.onFormSubmit()
.create();
```

In that case, try setting a default trigger in the app script selecting the "On Form Submit" event type.
[set Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZYJ0.png)

I hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Hey I believe you will just need to add another column to basically mark that the email has been sent before and if the "Sent Check" column is empty then send email. This will prevent duplicated emails.

Sorry if I got it wrong but from reading your code and your problem I understand that the `lastRow` entry of form 1 is sent before and when form 2 is submitted is will still send the same `lastRow` data in email?

Proposal:

```
 var sentcheck = values[12]; //Check if email has been sent before//
 var status = values[11];
 var ticketId = values[0];
 var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(values[1]), 'GMT+6', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a');
 var requestSubject = values[2];
 var requestType = values[2];
 var requestPriority = values[3];
 var requestDescription = values[4];
 var staffEmail = values[6];
 var facilityType = values[7];
 var facilityCode = values[8]
 
 if(sentcheck=='SENT') return; //skip if sent before//
 if(status=='Open'){
var subject = '[Ticket ID: ' + ticketId + '] ' + requestSubject;

// Email Text. You can add HTML code here - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
var htmlBody = 'Dear IRT Team,';
htmlBody += '<p>This is to notify that there is a new service request from Unimove IRT Helpdesk portal.</p>';
htmlBody += '<p><strong>Request Type:</strong> ' + requestType;
htmlBody += '<br><strong>Request Date:</strong> ' + timestamp;
htmlBody += '<br><strong>Priority:</strong> ' + requestPriority;
htmlBody += '<br><strong>Description:</strong> ' + requestDescription;
htmlBody += '<br><strong>Facility Type:</strong> ' + facilityType;
htmlBody += '<br><strong>Facility Code:</strong> ' + facilityCode;
htmlBody += '<br><strong>Staff Email:</strong> ' + staffEmail + '</p>';
htmlBody += '<p>Above details extracted from <a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14YicUUJeb3hopA7T7qydAN9ri__59_kmHfPpeURGlFg/edit" target="_blank">Unimove IRT Helpdesk (Responses)</a>.</p>';
htmlBody += '<p>Thank you.</p>';
htmlBody += '<p>Regards,<br>Unimove IRT Helpdesk</p>';

GmailApp.sendEmail('vasuki.rao@snapdeal.com', subject, '', {htmlBody:htmlBody, name: 'Unimove IRT Helpdesk', replyTo: 'vasuki.rao@snapdeal.com'}); 

responseSheet.getRange(rLastRow, 1, 1, lastCol).setValue('SENT'); //mark as sent when email has been delivered//
}
```

Comment: form2 submission needs to trigger email basis where it records response ex sheet1 and form1 submission needs to trigger email basis where it records response eg sheet2

Comment: I see. So your desired outcome if form2 get a submission submit email from sheet1 then if form1 gets a submission submit email from sheet2?

Please correct me if I am understanding your desired outcome wrongly

Comment: Correct, just reiterating for better clarity, whenever form2 is submitted linked to sheet1, email should trigger based on data available in sheet1 and whenever form1 is submitted linked to sheet2, email should trigger based on data available in sheet2.

Comment: Hey @VasukiRao did u try creating two functions, one for each form response? I think you can create one function for each form response, set a trigger for time driven (hour), then use a indicator to checkoff emails that have been sent. 

You might need to use a ForEach function for this: https://spreadsheet.dev/foreach-loop-in-apps-script

I have an example of ForEach loop here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71447225/send-email-from-sheets/71451867#71451867

Comment: Solve it by combining both the forms into single form with data validation as password to control form access

Comment: great! @VasukiRao